# How to use Array to refer to Rows/Columns in Cells object

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'd like to select range using

```
Range.(Cells(1,1), Cells(1,2)).Select
```

but instead of variables like 1 or 2 I'd like to use Array.
E.g

```
Z = Array(1,2,3)
Range.(Cells(Z(0),Z(1)), Cells(Z(1),Z(2))).Select
```

But VBA says that Application or Object defined error. I can easily refer to Z(1) in a MsgBox or everything else but I can't use it in `.Cells` object.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Using your code:

```
Range.(Cells(Z(0), Z(1)), Cells(Z(1), Z(2))).Select
```

i got error "Expected: identifier or bracketed expected"

This works for me:

```
Z = Array(1, 2, 3)
Range(Cells(Z(0), Z(1)), Cells(Z(1), Z(2))).Select
```